# How to pass error logging parameters in python django using a wrapper class/ decorator and use it for every method?

Tags: django, exception, django-rest-framework, wrapper, python-decorators

I am using Django-DB-logger for capturing my error logs in every method.I have multiple logging parameters----> user, class_name, method_name, module_name, ip_address, process_time. I need to get logs from every method. Given below is a sample method where I used my logging parameters.

```
            import logging
            import sys
            import socket
            import time
            from django.shortcuts import render
            from django.urls import resolve
            from rest_framework import status, request
            from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
            from rest_framework.response import Response
            from rest_framework.views import APIView

            class Request(APIView):

                @api_view(['GET'])
                def test_api_method(self):
                    startTime = time.time()
                    print('This is Test API')
                    db_logger = logging.getLogger('db')
                    try:
                        1 / 0
                    except Exception as e:
                        endTime = time.time()
                        db_logger.exception(e, extra={'user': self.user.username, 
                                                    'class_name': self.__class__.__name__,
                                                    'method_name': sys._getframe().f_code.co_name,
                                                    'module_name': __package__, 
                                                    'ip_address': socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
                                                    'process_time': endTime - startTime})

                    return Response({'data': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Rather than using all the parameters in every method like above, I want to use to decorator/ wrapper class (in a separate .py file) so that I can just call that decorator every time for capturing parameters during exception handling in all the methods in different .py files.
Kindly reply soon.

Comment: The parameters you are logging would only really be available in a class based Django view, would a mixin that provided a logging method suffice?

Comment: if so, can we use a wrapper class for that? If ou have some thoughts, kindly share the code for a wrapper class using this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got another method.

customdblogger_views.py

```
            import getpass
            import socket
            import time
            import logging

            class logEngine:

                def logger(request):
                    t1 = time.time()
                    params = {'user': request.user.username,
                              'ip_address': socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()),
                              'process_time': time.time() - t1,
                              }
                    return params

                def django_logger(self):
                    django_logger = logging.getLogger('db')
                    return django_logger


            attributes = logEngine().logger()
            db_logger = logEngine().django_logger()
```

## Create your views here.

```
            import sys

            from rest_framework import status
            from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
            from rest_framework.response import Response
            from rest_framework.views import APIView
            from CustomDBLogger.customdblogger_views import attributes, db_logger


            class Request(APIView):

                @api_view(['GET'])
                def test_api_method(self):

                    params2 = {'class_name': __class__.__name__,
                               'method_name': sys._getframe().f_code.co_name,
                               'module_name': __name__,
                               }
                    attributes.update(params2)

                    db_logger.info("Successfully entered into function", extra=attributes)

                    try:
                        1 / 0
                    except Exception as e:
                        db_logger.exception(e, extra=attributes)
                        return Response({'data': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
                    finally:
                        db_logger.info("exited from the function", extra=attributes)

                @api_view(['GET'])
                def test_logger(self):
                    params2 = {'class_name': __class__.__name__,
                               'method_name': sys._getframe().f_code.co_name,
                               'module_name': __name__,
                               }
                    attributes.update(params2)
                    db_logger.info("Successfully entered test_logger into function", extra=attributes)
                    try:
                        '2' + 2
                    except Exception as e:
                        db_logger.exception(e, extra=attributes)
                        return Response({'data': True}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```